# Smoothen border when using border-radius CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to use CSS and HTML to make drawing of a curved shape. Similar to the image bellow but get rid of those red circled areas and make the line smooth. Most of the CSS I've created by myself and any tips would be appreciated although this code will be used on a static HTML page only so no JS please. I'm looking for a solution that can be done with CSS and HTML only.

[image]

The CSS and HTML behind the image:

```css
:root {
    --border: 10px;
    --border-radius: 30px;
    --border-color: #000000;
    --margin: calc((var(--border)/2) * -1);
}

#container {
    margin: var(--border);
}

.row {
    font-size: 0;
}

.column {
    width: 32px;
    height: 24px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: var(--border) solid transparent;
    margin: var(--margin);
}

.top {
    border-top: var(--border) solid var(--border-color);
    margin-top: var(--margin)
}

.right {
    border-right: var(--border) solid var(--border-color);
    margin-right: var(--margin);
}

.bottom {
    border-bottom: var(--border) solid var(--border-color);
    margin-bottom: var(--margin);
}

.left {
    border-left: var(--border) solid var(--border-color);
    margin-left: var(--margin);
}

.top-left {
    border-top: var(--border) solid var(--border-color);
    border-left: var(--border) solid var(--border-color);
    border-radius: var(--border-radius) 0 0 0;
    margin-top: var(--margin);
    margin-left: var(--margin);
}

.top-right {
    border-top: var(--border) solid var(--border-color);
    border-right: var(--border) solid var(--border-color);
    border-radius: 0 var(--border-radius) 0 0;
    margin-top: var(--margin);
    margin-right: var(--margin);
}

.bottom-left {
    border-bottom: var(--border) solid var(--border-color);
    border-left: var(--border) solid var(--border-color);
    border-radius: 0 0 0 var(--border-radius);
    margin-bottom: var(--margin);
    margin-left: var(--margin);
}

.bottom-right {
    border-bottom: var(--border) solid var(--border-color);
    border-right: var(--border) solid var(--border-color);
    border-radius: 0 0 var(--border-radius) 0;
    margin-bottom: var(--margin);
    margin-right: var(--margin);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Design</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div class="frame">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="column top-left"></div>
                    <div class="column top"></div>
                    <div class="column top-right"></div>
                    <div class="column"></div>
                    <div class="column"></div>
                    <div class="column top-left"></div>
                    <div class="column top-right"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="column left"></div>
                    <div class="column"></div>
                    <div class="column"></div>
                    <div class="column bottom-left"></div>
                    <div class="column bottom-right"></div>
                    <div class="column"></div>
                    <div class="column right"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="column bottom-left"></div>
                    <div class="column"></div>
                    <div class="column"></div>
                    <div class="column"></div>
                    <div class="column"></div>
                    <div class="column"></div>
                    <div class="column bottom-right"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="column"></div>
                    <div class="column top"></div>
                    <div class="column top"></div>
                    <div class="column top"></div>
                    <div class="column top-right"></div>
                    <div class="column top-left"></div>
                    <div class="column right top-right"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="column"></div>
                    <div class="column"></div>
                    <div class="column"></div>
                    <div class="column"></div>
                    <div class="column bottom-right"></div>
                    <div class="column"></div>
                    <div class="column right"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="column top-left"></div>
                    <div class="column top"></div>
                    <div class="column top"></div>
                    <div class="column top"></div>
                    <div class="column"></div>
                    <div class="column"></div>
                    <div class="column right"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="column bottom-left"></div>
                    <div class="column bottom"></div>
                    <div class="column bottom"></div>
                    <div class="column bottom"></div>
                    <div class="column bottom"></div>
                    <div class="column bottom"></div>
                    <div class="column bottom-right"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is something like this possible to do with CSS? If yes, then how?

Comment: You could investigate using before or after pseudo elements to 'plug the gaps; though it doesn't help things get any less complex! As a complete alternative, have you considered SVG?

Comment: @AHaworth, I'm looking for CSS solution, this is not something I would like to draw but rather use CSS to make simple curved line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use `box-shadow` instead of `border`

for example: `box-shadow: 10px 10px 0 #000 inset;` for `.top-left` class

Comment: This looks promising, just needs tweaking i believe. I'll try variations and I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: thanks to your answer I've been able to achieve what I wanted. Working fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/al1en/akrv21cf/16/